# List of US Industry sector ETFs that map to ICB classification

Tags: equities, data, market-data, etf

I am in the prcess of carrying out intra-and intra sector analysis of US stocks, and am proxing sectors with sector ETFs. I therefore, need to catalog the list of US sector ETFs - but have been unable to source this (so far) online.

Is there a definitive list online, of the set of US exchange listed Industry sector ETFs (ideally, the sectors should map 1-1 to the [ICB](http://www.ftserussell.com/financial-data/industry-classification-benchmark-icb) classification of industry groups) - i.e. something akin to the **Euro STOXX sector indices**.

Comment: I am not familiar with ICB classification. Do the Sector SPDRs {XLF, XLK, XLV, XLP, XLY, XLE, XLB, XLI, XLU, RWR} meet your requirements?

Comment: http://www.sectorspdr.com/sectorspdr/ (note: RWR has been superseded by XLRE).

Comment: @noob2 Thanks. Yes, I am aware of the Sector SPDRS (and the link), however, they are based on GICS and only map approximately, to the ICB codes. I may have to use them however, if there is no alternative.

Comment: There is also a set which is based on MSCI classification, instead of GICS http://www.dummies.com/personal-finance/investing/vanguard-industry-sector-etfs/ However it may not help you. Sorry.